# Spark ThriftServer's caching of storage file paths for Hive tables

Tags: apache-spark

The first time, I queried a table through Hue while connecting to the Spark ThriftServer, and the HDFS storage path of this table was hdfs:///hive/warehouse/xxx.db/xxxx/1.orc.
Subsequently, I executed a Spark task to overwrite the data in this table, and at this point, the HDFS storage path of the table became hdfs:///hive/warehouse/xxx.db/xxxx/2.orc.
However, when I tried querying the same table again via Hue connected to the Spark ThriftServer, an exception was thrown, stating that the file hdfs:///hive/warehouse/xxx.db/xxxx/1.orc could not be found.

Based on my analysis, I suspect that the Spark ThriftServer might have cached the storage path of the table from the initial query, and during the second query, it did not refresh its cache, leading to this error. Are there experts familiar with this aspect who can offer guidance? How can I prevent such errors from occurring?